# Calling destructor in member function

Tags: c++, c++17

If we are implementing, for example, smart pointers, and we want to do `a = std::move(b)` --- we need to delete memory to which `a` is pointing, but can we call destructor inside move assignment operator, instead of copy-pasting destructor's function body?

**Is the behavior on calling destructor inside move-assignment defined?**

If it's not, are there any better ways dealing with it rather than copy-pasting destructor's body?

Comment: Why not create a new function for the "destruction" of the object, and call that when needed?

Comment: Can you please provide some code explaining what you are trying to do? Are you talking about calling the destructor on `this`?

Comment: If you call the destructor  you cannot assign to it anymore even if it would be legal to call dtor. So how that would be a solution?

Comment: @user17732522 yes, destructor on `this`.

Comment: If you call `delete this;` inside the move-assignment, then the object that is being moved to has been destructed.  After that point, there is no longer an object at the now dangling `this` address to manipulate.  So... probably the wrong technique.

Comment: @Eljay I think the intention here is doing `this->~shared_pointer();`

Comment: can you provide some code example which will clarify what do you mean?

Comment: @Eljay actually according to the standard object can be recreated in place, so it is possible to do that. Is it a viable solution is a big question though. But OP means calling destructor not `delete this`

Comment: Ahh, using `this->~Klass();` and `new(this) Klass;`, rather than `delete this;`.  (Replacing Klass with the actual class name.)  Polymorphic types may be trickier.  Wasn't clear to me in the OP's question.

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude said, the best way is to put the common logic in a function. In the case of a smart pointer, if you define `pointer release()` and `void reset(pointer = nullptr)`, then destruction is `reset()` and move-assignment is `reset(other.release())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explictly calling destuctor is technically available, you can use `this->~Object()` in non static method of the class `Object`.

However this is a bad practice. Consider use these instead.

```cpp
class Test {
 public:
  Test() {}

  ~Test() {
    Deallocate();
  }

  Test(const Test& other) = delete;

  Test(Test&& other) {
    Deallocate();
    // Do sth
  }

 private:
  void Deallocate() {
    // Do sth
  }
};
```

Comment: However, be extremely careful of exceptions happening after you `Deallocate`, so they don't leave your object in a broken state.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to call the destructor on `this` inside a member function and it has well-defined behavior.

However, that behavior involves ending the lifetime of the object `*this`. After the destructor call you are not allowed to access/use any members of the object anymore. This also has bad consequences in many situations, e.g. if the object has automatic storage duration the destructor will be called a second time on it during scope exit, which would cause undefined behavior.

So that isn't useful for what you want to do.

Although I **strongly advice against it**, in theory you could then follow the destructor call by construction of a new object at the same storage location via placement-new. However there are some preconditions outside the control of the class on when this is allowed without causing undefined behavior down the line. Under some conditions such a placement-new itself might be undefined behavior, under some conditions the names/references/pointers referring to the old object will not refer to the new one causing undefined behavior if used after the placement-new and under some conditions the lifetime of any parent object that `*this` is a subobject/member of will also be ended by such an operation, causing undefined behavior if used afterwards.

You can see a demonstration on how this would be implemented, against my advice and under certain (unstated) assumptions, in the standard (draft): https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#example-2

The linked example and the paragraph preceding it don't spell out all the conditions and possible problems with the approach that I hinted at above. Only the very specific usage of the class/function shown in the example is definitively allowed.

---

If you just want to reuse code, move the body of the destructor into a new member function and call that one from both locations requiring the same behavior.

Comment: Is it well defined to call a constructor from a member function?

Comment: @Slava There is no way to call a constructor explicitly. There is no syntax for it.

Comment: Placement new on `this` ?

Comment: @Slava Whether it is allowed, depends on how `this` was constructed, e.g. if it was a const complete object it is going to be UB. (Although then move assignment shouldn't be called on it) The new object might also not be transparently-replacable with the old one, e.g. if the object was a base class subobject.

Comment: So it is possible to reconstruct object after calling delete? Hmm interesting. I would not do that for sure, just curious.

Comment: Yea very interesting, so it is possible to implement it this way. it would be great if you add that into your answer for completeness.

Comment: @Slava I have added it, but it really shouldn't be used. It makes assumptions on the object that are outside the control of the class itself.

Comment: @Slava Also, I misread your comment. Reconstructing the object after `delete` is not allowed (since the storage will be gone). Only after a destructor call _may_ it be allowed.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean to say `delete`. I mean calling destructor.